# Getting Warning message while reading .XLS file using Java

Tags: java, excel, jxl

I am using 'jxl.jar' file to rad Excel (i.e xls) file.It's working fine.But i am getting below warning message while reading the file . Please anyone let me know the reason and solution for the same.

```
Warning:  Some cells exceeded the specified bounds.  Resizing sheet dimensions from 3x6 to 4x6
```

Answer (score 0):

This warning refers to some cell width is too small, the content of which exceeds the length of the cell.

Comment: How can i overcome this ?

Comment: @MadhuSudhanReddy That is only a warning. I think you can ignore it.